# Ormlite не вызывает onCreate()

Tags: android, база-данных, ormlite

есть MainActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DatabaseHelper.class);
    ...
}
```

и есть DatabaseHelper.java :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myappdb.sqlite";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        Log.d("mytg", "HERE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

и "HERE" не вижу в логах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если база создана ранее, то `onCreate` не будет вызываться. В случае если вы поменяете версию с 1 на 2, например, а потом на 3, будет вызван `onUpgrade`.

В простейшем варианте пока у вас идет разработка и содержимое базы может меняться и данные не важны можно в `onUpgrade` делает drop всех таблиц, и вызываете вручную `onCreate`, где таблицы пересоздадутся. Далее если меняете структуру базы, просто увеличиваете версию бд (в конструкторе последний параметр, у вас там сейчас 1).

ЗЫ ormlite тут ни причем.